# Hive job not starting

Tags: hadoop, centos, hive

I have created a new VM with hadoop on it 
(used this guide: http://alanxelsys.com/2014/02/01/hadoop-2-2-single-node-installation-on-centos-6-5/ )

I have created some tables with data on it.

when I run a "select * from table" query, I get the result,
when I try to run "Select * from table where..."

I get those lines:

```
Total jobs = 1
lunching job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
```

(Now I am waiting and nothing happened)

Any one have idea what I can do to fix it?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: As per the output you mentioned the Job is triggered. Do you have data in hive that matches your where condition?

Comment: Hi, yes I do have data, the query should return above 1,000 rows.